# Is every permutation of the first $k$ prime bases in $p_1^{q_1}+p_2^{q_2}+\dots+p_k^{q_k}$ a unique sum?

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

Or, is it possible to have two distinct permutations of the first $k$ primes for some $k$ such that using each prime once as a base and once as an exponent to form $k$ terms will yield identical sums?

e.g. $2^2+3^3+5^5+7^7$ is a valid candidate permutation for $k=4$, as is $7^2+3^3+2^5+5^7$; the requirement is that you use every prime in range exactly once as a base and once as an exponent. (Note that you can view this as permuting the bases only while the exponents are in fixed order, or the exponents only while the bases are fixed, or permute both; the effect is the same so long as you follow that requirement.)

There are definitely solutions for less stringent requirements, e.g. if the bases are prime and the exponents are the first $k$ positive integers instead of first $k$ primes, we have

$$3^1+5^2+2^3=5^1+2^2+3^3=36.$$

---

As per discussion below, I believe this can be effectively restated as:

Are there any two subsets $p,q$ of the primes such that

$$p_1^{q_1}+p_2^{q_2}+\ldots+p_{i}^{q_i}=p_{i+1}^{q_{i+1}}+\ldots+p_k^{q_k}?$$

Any primes in any order may be used, so long as all $p$ values are different, and all $q$ values are different.

---

**Clarification:**

There need to be an equal number of terms on each side of that equation.

Otherwise, $2^7+17^3=71^2$ would fit the bill. See also [Fermat-Catalan conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%E2%80%93Catalan_conjecture).

It also seems plausible that requiring the exponents be $3$ or higher would be sufficient.

Comment: Have you tried verifying this for small $k$?

Comment: A little bit. All I can say for certain is there's no solution for $k\leq 7$.

Comment: I verified it for $k=8,9,10$.  For $k=11$, my python script shut my computer down.

Comment: Ha, not surprised. This is one of those rare problems that I could really see going either way... though if I had to bet, I think it would be that all such sums are unique.

Comment: We need only find a solution for some subset of primes, using permutations of that subset for both the bases and exponents, and then we can fill in the unused primes as $p^p$ in both sums.

Comment: @nickgard I had the same thought. But even after running $10^7$ or $10^8$ trials of random pairs of 2-4 terms each to test for equality, I got nothing. I'm guessing this can only be solved through an analytical disproof, or some much smarter computation.

Comment: Interesting problem (+1). I do not think that we can do any better than brute force.

Comment: If I understand the comments correctly, upto $\ k=10\ $, no duplicate of sums appears . Right ?

Comment: @Peter That's it looks like. I only personally verified up through $k=7$, and then a bunch of random trials for $8 \leq k \leq 20$.

Comment: This seems likely to be false. I did some more rigorous number crunching, and more importantly, realized it's awfully similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal_conjecture, a generalization of Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: @Trevor I think, this problem is rather more difficult than Beal's conjecture. One duplicate would however solve the conjecture in the negative sense. A positive proof (no duplicates appear) will be an enormous task.